# is there a way to send in parameters with JavaScript Array.prototype.find?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following, standard use of Array.prototype.find:

```
var getObject = myObjects.find(callback);
```

with:

```
var callback = function(object) {
    return object === 'myValue'
}
```

Is there a way to inject another parameter?  So we'd have, say:

```
var getObject = myObjects.find(callback, mySearchTerm);
```

with:

```
var callback = function(element, mySearchTerm) {
    return element === mySearchTerm;
}
```

?

Comment: Use a wrapper function, bind them...

Comment: IE is not support array.find , are you sure you want this solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
var term = 'some term';
var getObject = myObjects.find(function(item){return callback(item, term)});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure over the parameter, like

```
var callback = function (value) {
        return function(object) {
           return object === value;
        };
    };
```

Call the callback with parameter

```
var getObject = myObjects.find(callback(mySearchTerm));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper function for a reusable solution.

Example:

```js
var myObjects = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4];

var search = function(data, mySearchTerm) {
  var callback = function(element) {
    return element === mySearchTerm;
  };
  return data.find(callback)
};

var getObject = search(myObjects, 2);

console.log(getObject);
```

Or

```js
var myObjects = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4];
var mySearchTerm = 2;
var callback = function(object) {
    return object === mySearchTerm;
};
var getObject = myObjects.find(function(element) {
  return callback(element, mySearchTerm);
});
console.log(getObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function myFind(what){
  function findCherries(fruit) { 
      return fruit.name === what;
  }
  return inventory.find(findCherries)
}

console.log(myFind("cherries"));
```

But again, IE doesn't support array.find() !